# Why is the Electron parent window still blocked after closing a modal window?

Tags: typescript, dialog, electron

- Electron version: 1.7.2
- Operating system: Windows 10

#### Expected behavior

Mouse control returns to the parent window.

#### Actual behavior

Mouse input to the parent window becomes permanently blocked.

#### How to reproduce

Sample code for dialog manager in the main application's renderer process:

```
class DialogManager {
    private _dialogWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow | null = null;
    private _finalizing: boolean = false;
    private _dialogResultCompletion: q.Deferred<any> = null;

    /**
     * Entry point.
     *
     * @param args Arguments to be passed to the dialog.
     */
    public getDialogResult(args: any): Promise<any> {
        try {
            this.openDialog(args);
        } catch (error) {
            return q.reject(error);
        }

        this._dialogResultCompletion = q.defer<any>();

        return this._dialogResultCompletion.promise;
    }

   private openDialog(id: string, args: any): void {
        if (this.isDialogOpen()) {
            throw new Error("A dialog is already open. Make sure you're not opening a dialog from another dialog and that all other dialogs are closed.");
        }

        this._finalizing = false;

        this._dialogWindow = new remote.BrowserWindow({
            frame: true,
            center: true,
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            parent: remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(),
            resizable: false,
            show: false,
            skipTaskbar: true,
            useContentSize: true
        });

        let onReady = () => {
            if (!!this._dialogWindow) {
                console.warn("Dialog is now ready");
                // Remove when done.
                this._dialogWindow.show();
                this._dialogWindow.webContents.send("dialog-init", { /* initialization parameters */ });
            }
        };

        let onInit = (e, error) => {
            if (!!error) {
                this.finalize(error, undefined);
                this._dialogResultCompletion.reject(error);
            } else {
                console.warn("Dialog is now initialized");

                this._dialogWindow.show();
            }
        };

        let onFinalize = (e, error, result) => {
            this._finalizing = true;

            if (!!this._dialogWindow) {
                this._dialogWindow.close();
            }

            this.finalize(error, result);
        }

        let onCloseOrCrash = (e, error, result) => {
            if (!this._finalizing) {
                this.finalize(error, result);
            }
            this._dialogWindow = null;
        }

        this._dialogWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
        this._dialogWindow.loadURL("http://path/to/my/dialog.html");

        this._dialogWindow.once("ready-to-show", onReady);
        remote.ipcMain.once("did-dialog-init", onInit);
        remote.ipcMain.once("dialog-finalize", onFinalize);

        // Handle when the user force closes the window (such as clicking the X in Windows)
        this._dialogWindow.once("closed", onCloseOrCrash);

        // Handle the possibility of the dialog process crashing
        this._dialogWindow.webContents.once("crashed", (e) => { onCloseOrCrash(e, "The dialog renderer process crashed", undefined); });
    }

    private finalize(error: any | undefined, result: any | undefined) {
        if (!!error) {
            console.warn("Dialog is now finalizing with an error");
            this._dialogResultCompletion.reject(error);
        } else {
            console.warn("Dialog is now finalizing with a result");
            this._dialogResultCompletion.resolve(result);
        }
    }

    private isDialogOpen(): boolean {
        return !!this._dialogWindow;
    }
}

let instance = new DialogManager();

export default instance;
```

Sample code for dialog renderer process (this file is required by the HTML file):

```
// Initially show only the default dialog panel
$(".dialog-panel").hide();
$("#default-panel").show();

$(document)
    .keyup((e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === KeyCodes.Esc) {
            ipcRenderer.send("dialog-finalize", undefined, null);
        }
    })
    .ready(() => {
        ipcRenderer.send("dialog-ready");
    });

ipcRenderer.once("dialog-init", (e, message) => {
    try {
        // A Knockout view model object is created based on the arguments passed from the dialog manager
        let viewModel: any;

        // Initialization...

        viewModel.currentPanel.subscribe((result) => {
            $(".dialog-panel").hide();
            $("#" + result).show().focus();
        });

        // We subscribe to the `dialogResult` observable so that we may
        // automatically close the dialog when its value is set.
        viewModel.dialogResult.subscribe((result) => {
            ipcRenderer.send("dialog-finalize", undefined, result);
        });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    } catch (error) {
        ipcRenderer.send("dialog-finalize", error.message);
    }
});

(<any>process).on("unhandledException", (err) => {
    ipcRenderer.send("dialog-finalize", err.message);
});
```

Stepping through the above code, the dialog window opens and closes, following all the expected code paths. But after the dialog window is closed, and the reference is set to `null`, mouse control doesn't return to the parent window.

I'm not doing something wrong, am I?

I have noticed from time to time that `_dialogWindow` and `_finalizing` aren't always what I expect them to be. Sometimes _finalizing is already set to `true` before I've set it. Sometimes `_dialogWindow` is `null` when closing but before I've actually set it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not doing something wrong, am I?

No you're doing anything wrong. I think that's just the way Electron works sadly.

To get around it you can just call the `.focus()` function to focus on the parent window.

Something like this:

```
this._parentWindow.focus();
```

[Ref.](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winfocus)

Comment: Good suggestion, but sadly it doesn't work. Mouse input is still blocked. They weird thing is keyboard input is *not* blocked. The Electron people apparently discourage the overuse of the `remote` module; managing windows in a renderer process is a big red flag.